# Linux sendmail problem

Tags: linux

I have Fedora installation running a web app (LAMP configuration) that sends emails every now and then.
PHP calls the sendmail utility that is configured as a relay agent.
Sendmail hands off the email to an Exchange server.

Yesterday sendmail stopped sending emails.
There is nothing in the logs - /var/log/messages, /var/log/maillog etc....that points to any sort of error. The server was not restarted and the sendmail service is running fine and listening on port 25 (verified using lsof).

There is no error to report that i can find.
The emails simply get queued and the sendmail utility doesn;t send them.
In the maillog the emails show as "stat=queued"

I have restarted the server, restarted the sendmail service (which shows no errors) and even did a wireshark trace when sending an email, filtering for the exchange server, to see if sendmail even attempts to connect to it and nothing shows up.

Anyone have any suggestion of anywhere else to look?
I've little experience of sendmail - i configured it as a transfer agent bout a year ago and since then its been fine - no problems.
Also the number of emails the web app sends is minimal (i.e. maybe 3/4 a day).

I can send emails using Perl and the Perl sendmail module but not using PHP and the sendmail utility?

Anyone have any ideas?
Much appreciated

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and don't know what to do. Reinstalling sendmail doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: What happens if you explicitly flush the queue by running 'sendmail -q' on the server?  Also, what sendmail processes show up when you run 'ps -fe'?

Comment: The clue here is that "I can send emails using Perl and the Perl sendmail module but not using PHP and the sendmail utility?" Nothing is likely wrong with sendmail, then, right?  Confirm by trying to send an e-mail from the BASH shell.  If the messages are getting backed up in queue from PHP, but not Perl then maybe the messages from PHP are malformed.  Was PHP recently upgraded? What's the last modified date on /etc/php.ini? Have a good known backup that you can compare with the diff command?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved: OK this issue turned out to be a DNS configuration issue.
After running a trace on the server filtering for the DNS server, sendmail was getting a SERVFAIL response from the DNS server when querying for the exchange server.
Turns out some lemon tried to configure a VOIP client on the server and must have set the hostname to localhost.localdomain.
The trace was showing that the DNS query was appending a localdomain string to the end of the DNS query - after setting the hostname back the DNS queries were fine and sendmail could send emails again.
Many thanks for the replies and apologies for not editing my oringinal question
I reset all my network configuration settings (DNS, Hostname etc...)

Answer (score 0):

What are the results of `mailq`? Can you try forcing the sendmail queue using `sendmail -v -q`?

That should give some idea of why the messages are stalled. This is usually a network hostname or DNS issue. See what the results of those commands are, though.

```
Running /var/spool/mqueue/p0LLrgqL000635 (sequence 1 of 683)
<root@ppro.abc.com>... Connecting to ppro.abc.com. via esmtp...
<root@ppro.abc.com>... Deferred: Connection refused by ppro.abc.com.

Running /var/spool/mqueue/p0LLrgqO000635 (sequence 2 of 683)
<root@ppro.123.com>... Deferred: Connection refused by ppro.123.com.

Running /var/spool/mqueue/p0LLrgqN000635 (sequence 3 of 683)
<root@ppro.xyz.com>... Deferred: Connection refused by ppro.xyz.com.
```